# Dynamically adding WCF services in IIS 7

Tags: .net, wcf

I tried searching for a solution to this but so far I had no luck.

I have a series of class libraries each library (module/plugin) implements one or more WCF services.
Now I want a "hosting" project where I can add all these services based on which plugins that are accessible. I know that I can use fileless activiation and thus do it all configuration time, but I would much rather have some code that looks at the installed plugins (I have the code for that), and adds the exposed services runtime. The whole thing should be hosted in IIS 7 (or above) using WAS, since I need TCP bindings as well as HTTP.

What I found was that it seems to be possible using the ASP.NET RouteTable class (adding types in Application_Start), but my understanding is that this will limit me to use HTTP hosting only.

I guess what I want is an API for the WAS that I can hook into and add "endpoints/activations", but so far I have not been able to find anything. Something equivalent to the following config:

```
<serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="AwesomeService.svc" service="Classlibrary.WCF.AwesomeService"/>
</serviceActivations>
```

Anyone knows how such a thing could be done?

Comment: Just to clarify, i know i can do something like OperationContext.Current.Host.AddServiceEndpoint() and add an endpoint like that, but then i loose all the "configuration power" that have been provided by standardendpoints etc in the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully used the approach described here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/archive/2011/08/29/registering-a-wcf-service-dynamically.aspx

It uses some reflection hacking to access a private field on the ServiceHostingEnvironment class to add custom "configuration-based activation" entries at runtime.

I elected to use an HttpModule to register the service activation elements like this:

```
    public class ServiceRegistrationModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            // Discover and register your services here
            RegisterService("~/Some/Path.svc", null, "The full service class name");
        }

        static object _syncRoot = new object();
        static Hashtable serviceActivations;

        private static void RegisterService(string addr, string factory, string service)
        {
            // This is the code that injects the service activation configuration.
            // In WCF 4 we have the "not very well known" CBA Services (Configuration Based Activation)
            // to allow us to define "file-less" WCF Services (like our Service2 here in this demo) where
            // we have a section in our web.config to register services without the need of having a physical .svc file.
            // The section in the web.config looks like this:
            //
            //      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >
            //          <serviceActivations>
            //              <add relativeAddress="Service2.svc" service="WcfService2.Service2" />
            //          </serviceActivations>
            //      </serviceHostingEnvironment>
            //
            // And is this configuration what we are going to inject at runtime to simulate having that 
            // information in our web.config, while we haven't.

            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                if (serviceActivations == null)
                {
                    var ensureInitialized = typeof(ServiceHostingEnvironment).GetMethod("EnsureInitialized");
                    ensureInitialized.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
                    var hostingManagerField = typeof(ServiceHostingEnvironment).GetField("hostingManager", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField);
                    var hostingManager = hostingManagerField.GetValue(null);
                    var serviceActivationsField = hostingManager.GetType().GetField("serviceActivations", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField);
                    serviceActivations = (Hashtable)serviceActivationsField.GetValue(hostingManager);
                }

                if (!serviceActivations.ContainsKey(addr))
                {
                    string value = string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", addr, factory, service);
                    serviceActivations.Add(addr, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The downside of using an HttpModule is that it does not work really for TCP-based endpoints.  That wasn't a concern for me.  If it's a problem for you, the blog post I referenced above describes an approach that works for TCP-based endpoints.

Comment: May I please know whether it will work with .NET 4.0